# Keras flow label tensors from directory

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using convolutional neural networks to predict vegetation growth. My input is a (n,51,51,1) terrain elevation tensor, and the label is a (n,51,51,1) vegetation tensor.

Since flow from directory uses foldernames as labels, this is a bit of a problem. My network is performing well, but having to have all the data in memory is a bit limiting. If anyone knows how to setup a `flow from directory` for this problem I would appreciate it. I'm using R as an interface to keras and tensorflow, but solutions in python are welcome too. Included the picture in case it wasn't clear what I'm doing. Thanks! [image: elevation to vegitation]

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem you are trying to solve. Image creation is another can of worms than classification (which is what you are talking about)

You can check [this](https://phillipi.github.io/pix2pix/) article that talks more in depth about the generational networks.

Another way to think about it, is to have the last output layer with 51*51 hidden units and do regression. By this I mean to treat it as a regression problem where you do regression on each pixel individually.

Comment: Thanks for the link, also I already have a working model, just want to cut down the memory usage by avoid loading all data into memory. Need a flow from directory which takes the other image as the label.

Comment: And crazy paper what neural nets can do is incredible. I see they do have some type of flow generator implemented.